# Fill color is not working for my function (Python turtle graphics)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

The `fillcolor()` is not working at all in this function -- I can not figure out why. It worked in all of my other functions:

```
from turtle import Turtle

from random import randint

t = Turtle()

def rocks():
    for i in range(5):
        t.penup()
        t.goto(randint(-300,0), randint(-200,0))

        for x in range(40):
            t.pendown()
            t.fillcolor("gray")
            t.fillcolor()
            t.begin_fill()
            t.forward(5)
            t.left(25)
            t.right(27)
            t.forward(5)
            t.right(20)
            t.end_fill()

    t.speed("fastest")

rocks()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have the `begin_fill()` & `end_fill()` *inside* your loop which means they are trying to fill short line segments.  You need them *around* your loop to fill the entire shape:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randint

def rocks(t):
    t.fillcolor('gray')

    for _ in range(5):
        t.penup()
        t.goto(randint(-300, 0), randint(-200, 0))

        t.begin_fill()
        for _ in range(15):
            t.pendown()
            t.forward(5)
            t.right(2)
            t.forward(5)
            t.right(22)
        t.end_fill()

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')

rocks(turtle)

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]